# Nginx website shows "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm trying to use 1 DigitalOcean Droplet to host 2 different websites with 2 domains using NGINX Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to follow this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

I own both domains that are pointing to the droplet. Let's say the domains are janedoe.com and johndoe.com. janedoe.com uses Lets Encrypt for tls. Johndoe.com does not use ssl/tls.

These are my sites-available configs:

Janedoe.com:

```
server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name janedoe.com www.janedoe.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        # SSL configuration

        include snippets/ssl-janedoe.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        root /var/www/janedoe.com/html;
        index index.php index.html;
        error_page 404 /404.php;

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        location ~ \.php$ {
           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

               # With php7.0-cgi alone:
#               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
               # With php7.0-fpm:
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

}
```

Johndoe.com:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
        server_name johndoe.com www.johndoe.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        root /var/www/johndoe.com/html;
        index index.php index.html;
        error_page 404 /404.php;

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        location ~ \.php$ {
               include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

               # With php7.0-cgi alone:
#               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
               # With php7.0-fpm:
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

}
```

I was also wondering if my /etc/hosts file was correct

```
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
#
127.0.1.1 doe-2gb-nyc1-01 doe-2gb-nyc1-01


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Here is my /etc/nginx

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml applicati$

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
#       include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My problem is visiting either site will redirect you to janedoe.com which says

```
This page isn’t working

janedoe.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I've cleared my cookies, used different browsers, etc.

Please let me know if there is any more information that would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.